# How to turn a row with csv into a column of unique rows with repeating information

Tags: excel, vba

I'm converting information from my Brick-and-Morter store into a web store using Excel as my main powerhouse for translation of format.  My POS database is Dataflex 3.1c, and the web store uses Maria (SQL). (All of that in case somebody knows a connector for these two disparate products, none so far have done the job). What I need to do right now is take a two column spreadsheet using CSV, and turn it into a two column spreadsheet that separates out the CSV values and repeats the identifier number per row. Example below. Notice no row breaks when a value is not transferred (number 19), and the repeated column one identifier in Table 2. The two tables are stored on separate worksheets, so that should make it easier, I would think. I do assume this will be answerable in VBA, but I really don't know.  Thank you for all of your help, fellows! My apologies on the poor editing of the tables, Table 1 has no spaces in between the rows either.

Table 1 (Current setup):

```
Column1    Column2
17         70,89,90,91
18         101,91,89,90,44
19
20         99,89,70,101
```

Table 2 (Desired results):

```
Column1    Column2
17         70
17         89
17         90
17         91
18         101
18         91
18         89
18         90
18         44
20         99
20         89
20         70
20         101
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, this isn't a "code for me" site, we help with specific problems you're encountering in your code.  If you are looking for a place to start, google the following: `Excel VBA Loop over each cell in a range`, `Excel VBA Split Function`.  From there you should be able to put something together to attempt accomplishing this.  If you get stuck and have a specific question, feel free to come back and edit your question so we can address what stumped you.

Comment: Pointing me in the right direction is definitely helpful, thank you!  I will try to get something together and go from there!

Comment: Pretty simple to do with Power Query (found in Excel 2010+).  Delete the row where column 2 is empty; split column 2 using the comma; then select column 1 and `unpivot other columns`

Comment: If this is not going to a repeated process, I expect you could do this easier without coding/vba like I think @RonRosenfeld is suggesting. I only code vba to avoid doing tasks repetitively, but for doing something once, generally excel already has a good function built it,

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Actually, once he develops the Query, it can be used repeatedly, easily, should the underlying data change. The Query remains an integral part of the workbook.